# "sudo apt purge wine" not removing the "~/.wine" config folder on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, wine

`sudo apt purge wine` not removing the `~/.wine` config folder on ubuntu 20.04?
Is this intended behavior? How do i get rid of this folder. Just do `rm -rf ~/.wine` or is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. `.wine` is a hidden user configuration folder. The user configuration data are considered to be from the user. System wide installed software will never remove files from your home folder when you remove the software.

This happens not only out of "noble" principles, but also for down-to-earth technical reasons: the installation software would need to scan which users are on the system, and which users have used the software, hence have its configuration files.

Bottom line: all files and folders in your home folder are exclusively yours to manage.

Yes, the command you provide will remove the folder. You can use any tool you want to delete the folder.